# Unable to launch vagrant-lxc

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

I'm trying to launch vagrant-lxc on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using the latest Vagrant download (rather than the ancient version in the Debian repos).

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-lxc
```

runs successfully, as does:

```
vagrant init fgrehm/precise64-lxc
```

I ran

```
sudo vagrant lxc sudoers
```

to handle the sudo issues mentioned [here](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-lxc#avoiding-sudo-passwords).
But when I run

```
vagrant up --provider=lxc
```

(both with and without sudo) the container doesn't load, spitting out this:

```
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'lxc' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'fgrehm/precise64-lxc' is up to date...
==> default: Setting up mount entries for shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/ubuntu
==> default: Starting container...
There was an error executing ["sudo", "/usr/local/bin/vagrant-lxc-wrapper", "lxc-start", "-d", "--name", "ubuntu_default_1456156125505_47833"]

For more information on the failure, enable detailed logging by
setting the environment variable VAGRANT_LOG to DEBUG
```

Here's the log output I'm getting (from /var/log/lxc/ ubuntu_default_1456156125505_47833.log):

```
lxc-start 1456158555.539 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:884 - failed initializing cgroup support
  lxc-start 1456158555.568 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1121 - failed to spawn 'ubuntu_default_1456156125505_47833'
  lxc-start 1456158555.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:341 - The container failed to start.
  lxc-start 1456158555.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:343 - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
  lxc-start 1456158555.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - lxc_start.c:main:345 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Go into `/home/<USERNAME>/.vagrant.d/boxes/fgrehm/precise64-lxc/.../lxc/lxc-config`
file and
comment out:
`lxc.pivotdir = lxc_putold`
the do `vigrant up` again it should work!